# ionic\cordova jsonp works in browser but not on ANDROID

Tags: android, cordova, cross-domain, ionic-framework

i saw some similar questions but still didn't manage to find a solution.
the problem is as follows:

I have an html5 app which developed using Ionic.

when i use 'ionic serve' my JSONP cross domain calls work as expected.
when i create the application using 'ionic build' and then install the application on my android phone using the apk i get 404 on my jsonp.

i altered the config.xml and added a child element to the  element:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

still the same result.

if i take the jsonp url and paste in the my phone Chrome i can see the result as expected - so no network issue.

the communication is http (not secure)

I assume i'm missing some configuration but can't figure out which.

I'll appreciate any kind of help. thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to look at the console if there is not any exception? I had a similar problem and eventually it was because I had a path to the templates with small initial letters but on the file system are large. Chrome did not mind but the phone did.

Comment: how can i view the console? i dont know how to debug the application on my phone. if you have a good reference please post it.

Comment: 1. install https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adb/dpngiggdglpdnjdoaefidgiigpemgage

Comment: 2. Enable Developer options on your cellphone and enable debugging http://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm

Comment: 3. Switch Connection on your cellphone from MTP to Camera. In top console with plugged usb cable.

Comment: 4. Start your app and open ADB plugin in your chrome. Click on your application in ADB. Enjoy! :)

Comment: i'll give a try and will update you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. the steps are as follows:

install cordova whitelist plugin from command line:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

add access tag to config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

I also had to remove the application completely and install it again.
not just overwriting.